I can't adjust the brightness on Ubuntu 24.04
I need your help. I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my new laptop and I cannot adjust the brightness of my screen. I have tried all kinds of solutions and none of them work for me. I do not know what to do. Please does anyone have a solution? THANK YOU
